# Как автоматически создать таблицу на основе сущности с помощью Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Я тренируюсь использовать JPA, для понимания работы сущностей, аннотаций, менеджера сущностей описываю достаточно сложные или новые сущности. Чтобы использовать EntityManager у меня должны быть созданы таблицы. Руками через SQL со всеми зависимостями их не очень легко создавать. Я знаю, что можно настроить hibernate что бы он сам создавал таблицы на основе сущностей. Я искал в интернете, на киберфоруме, на стэковерлоф, на туториалах от хибернейта, но все равно не понял до конца как это сделать. Единственное, что я понял - что в `persistence.xml` надо указать строку  `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>`. Я указал, но ничего не происходит при запуске хибернейта, таблиц не появляются в бд. Что мне сделать, что бы у меня создались таблицы на основе сущностей которые я описал? Может кто то пошагово описать все шаги которые я должен сделать чтобы получить бд на основе сущности?

Вот логи которые идут после подключения хибернейта к пользователю бд:

```
апр. 05, 2019 3:29:12 ПП org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
апр. 05, 2019 3:29:12 ПП org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
апр. 05, 2019 3:29:12 ПП org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
апр. 05, 2019 3:29:13 ПП org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

UPD Теперь другая ошибка при создании таблицы. Вот логи:

```
Hibernate: 

    create table User (
       id int4 not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        password varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
апр. 05, 2019 3:45:41 ПП org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table User (
       id int4 not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        password varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table User (
       id int4 not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        password varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"
  Позиция: 20
```

Вот класс User, на позиции 20 там ничего такого нет:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String password, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(name, user.name)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(password, user.password);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop  попробуйте

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko все равно ничего. Я просто не очень понимаю, когда и как она должна создаваться(автоматически когда я запускаю проект и стартует хибер?) и где(у того пользователя которого я в persistence.xml указал?).

Comment: spring-boot подключен?

Comment: А остальное значит работает? Вы ключевое слово hibernate не пропускаете, как в вопросе, в названии свойства?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko блин, точно! Вроде код генерировался идеей и там этого не было. Только сейчас другая ошибка, при создании таблицы, добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Таблица с именем User запрещена в гибернейте. Ответ на второй вопрос))

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko спасибо, помогли) Может напишите ответ а я его приму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пропустили ключевое слово **hibernate** в названии свойства

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Ответ на второй вопрос: hibernate запрещает создавать таблицы с именем `User`.

Answer (score 3):

Если изначально следовать [туториалу](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) по настройки проекта, то есть использую `Spring-Boot`

Достаточно в `src/main/resources/application.properties` прописать

```
// Для автоматического создание таблиц на основание сущностей 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Позже после создание, таблиц рекомендуются перевести данную настройку в

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Comment: Не, у меня без спринга

Comment: @Алексей сорри не сразу заметил

Comment: @notaProgrammer до этого был вопрос аналогичный, который вы кстати тоже про минусовали, по этому тут я решил что все таки идет речь про spring. Для спринга это рабочий пример. Что я и пишу в ответе. Если бы я давал неправильный ответ, то да, минусовать правильно. А сейчас, я вас не понимаю

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример `persistence unit` для соединения с `H2 (in-memory)` базой данных:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="com.example">
        <!-- Ваши сущности -->
        <class>com.example.Event</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Когда `Persistence Provider` (Hibernate) создает таблицы из сущностей?** Если говорить просто и не вдаваться во внутреннюю реализацию, то при создании `EntityManagerFactory`, то есть, грубо говоря, после строки

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.example");
```

все таблицы будут созданы.

Comment: Спасибо, плюсанул

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы очень хотите разобраться, что происходит, когда Вы пытаетесь построить таблицы на основе entity, то посмотрите на класс org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport (пакет находится в hibernate-core.jar). У класса имеется метод main, который можно запустить с передачей параметров (например в eclipse откройте этот класс и по правой клавише вызовите Run as > run configuration и на закладке Arguments допустим такие параметры --target=SCRIPT --config=my_hibernate.cfg.xml --output=script.txt  --implicit-naming=legacy-hbm  --physical-naming= com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNamingStrategy ). Полный список параметров см. в методе parseCommandLineArgs(). 
Кроме того, имеется класс  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate, который используется когда надо получить изменеия в БД, после изменения entity.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо задать следующий параметр

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете конфигурацию **hibernate.properties** без Spring, то там нужно использовать строчку:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Варианты параметра:

**validate** - Hibernate проверит, совпадают ли имена и типа колонок и полей в базе и в аннотациях. Это самый частый режим.

**update** - Hibernate обновит таблицы в базе, если они или их колонки отличаются от ожидаемых.

**create** - Hibernate удалит все таблицы в базе и создаст их заново на основе данных из аннотаций.

**create-drop** - в начале работы Hibernate создаст все таблицы, в конце работы удалит их за собой.

**none** - Hibernate вообще ничего не будет делать. Если где-то база не совпадает с ожиданием, то будут сыпаться ошибки во время выполнения запросов.